# Отправка смс на указанный номер

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, sms

Допустим есть форма на сайте, в нее вбивается телефон, затем по нажатию кнопки на указанный номер отправляется сообщение.

Интересуют некоторые вопросы по данной теме.

1) Насколько это дорого?

2) Насколько сложно это реализовать (с протоколами sms не работал никогда)

Comment: Вы планируете воспользоваться сторонними сервисами или у вас собственный сервер, который имеет GSM плату?

Comment: У меня нету ничего, кроме бесплатного "хоста"   Azure

Comment: Я использую сервис Turbosms. Стоимость смс от 0,25 гривен. У них есть готовый пример для работы на .NET через api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть прекрасный сервис [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms). Он позволяет посылать SMS, делать звонки, принимать звонки. У них очень хорошая документация с примерами на разных языках, вот [руководство на C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/server-notifications/csharp/mvc)