# Как отправлять СМС сообщения с помощью кода на C#? Есть ли способы делать это бесплатно?

Tags: c#

Нужно для своего проекта, чтобы плохие юзеры могли баниться по телефону.

Comment: При чем тут C#? СМС отправляются через различных операторов (или агрегаторов), платно или бесплатно - зависит как раз от них. Если эти самые операторы предоставляют API - то там уже и можно задуматься над отправкой СМС используя C#.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отправка смс на указанный номер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649331/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bc%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть разные сервисы, которые предоставляют API. На счет бесплатно... тут не думаю, скорее всего придется заплатить(но не думаю что много, даже если проект ради интереса не думаю что цена отпугнет). Из таких сервисов знаю twillo на он с российскими номерами не работает. Есть вот [такой](https://www.smsfeedback.ru/) сервис вроде бы работает с российскими номерами